# Angular material is there any notify function on every mat-tree re-render

Tags: angular, typescript, tree, angular6, angular-material2

I have a material tree and on every data change the tree is re- rendered

The data change is provided through subject or re-assign array

```
this.dataChange.next(newdata);
```

Or

```
this.dataSource.data = newdata;
```

Is there any mechanism to capture or capture change detection the change I mean every re-render. I mean like a function or life cycle hook attached to it and it should catch every re-render?

If any one go through it please guide me...

Comment: any solution for this ?